# In Apache .htaccess file using mod_rewrite, is it possible to force www AND force https for a domain?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.co.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

thats for the www, but I cannot figure out in a one-pass way how to force the https too?

Answer (score 1):

Use the SERVER_PROTOCOL variable:

```
RewriteCond ${SERVER_PROTOCOL} !^https [NC]
```

Comment: I think this is what I need to do, but perhaps it can be simplified?

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.co.uk$ [NC]


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]